# How to determine which indexes will optimize the speed of a fixed SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a rather large SQL query which uses `join` to connect over 40 tables.

I am wondering if there is some way to automatically analyze the SQL query performance over time, and recommend which indexes should be added to which tables and columns to minimize the query latency?

Comment: Doesn't SQL server just tell you what missing indexes could be added to improve performance if you include the execution plan?

Comment: You can use the estimated execution plan, it will tell you if there are indexes that you can add, otherwise there are multiple products online that can help with that as well

Comment: The Database Tuning Advisor is the most comprehensive utility for this kind of analysis.

Comment: check this tutorial :http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/277/index-scans-and-table-scans

Comment: Any chance of splitting that query into smaller pieces? With 40 tables there's also quite a big risk that query plan creation will time out and that can create really bad plans. You can see that from the properties of the leftmost operation in the plan: http://www.scarydba.com/2010/11/18/reason-for-early-termination-of-statement/

Comment: @JamesZ Excellent link, thanks. I did not know that it's possible for the query optimiser to time out, and if so, how to identify and rectify this situation.